# Can I use perfume that contain alcohol and will it affect my prayer?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, alcohol, perfume

I want to know is it haram to use perfume that contain alcohol and if I use it will my Salat and prayers will be accepted?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/164448

Comment: Related to some extent https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31028/13438

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there are nothing against us using perfume that contains alcohol other than for the sake of being careful.

> "That which intoxicates in large quantities is prohibited in small
>   quantities." (Abu Dawud, Tirmidhi, Ibn Majah, and others, with a sound
>   chain of narrators)

Since it has been understood that alcohol have the qualities of being intoxicating in large quantities, it would be better for us to avoid it in the cases where it accidentally gets consumed.

Related to Salah, according to Quran, An-Nisa verse 43:

> O you who have believed, do not approach prayer while you are
>   intoxicated until you know what you are saying or in a state of
>   janabah, except those passing through [a place of prayer], until you
>   have washed [your whole body]. And if you are ill or on a journey or
>   one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have
>   contacted women and find no water, then seek clean earth and wipe over
>   your faces and your hands [with it]. Indeed, Allah is ever Pardoning
>   and Forgiving.

There should be nothing against it since perfume in alcohol doesn't causes intoxication.

It should be noted though, that some [scholar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/31083/24208) rules that alcohol is najis, which would cause Salah to be incomplete since it doesn't comply with the requirements of being clean from Najis.

Reference: [If "that which intoxicates in large quantities" is haram, does that mean water is haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16489/if-that-which-intoxicates-in-large-quantities-is-haram-does-that-mean-water-i)

Comment: Maybe you should comment on the fact that some scholars say that alcohol is najas. Might be relevant.